# Not understanding equality in a proof

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, modular-forms

Hello I am studying a paper named "Cycle integrals of the j functions and mock modular forms". I want to ask how we get equality which a marked as red in the image. Assumptions are

We are taking $Q=[a,b,c]$ be binary quadratic form with discriminant d>0 not a square and let $S_Q$ be the oriented semicircle defined by $a\tau^2 +bRe\tau +c=0$ for $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$ which is directed counterclockwise if a>0 and clockwise if a<0. For any $z\in S_Q$ let $C_Q$ be the directed arc on $S_Q$ from z to $g_Q z$ where $g_Q z= \frac{\frac{t+bu}{2}z+cu}{-au +\frac{t-bu}{2}}$ where t,u are smallest positive integral solutions of $t^2 -du^2=4$. Basically  i want to ask how we changed integral to the semicircle $S_Q$ from the integration over arc $C_Q$. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Note that the outer sum has changed. This is a process known as unfolding.

Comment: Sir, can we say that $S_Q$ is disjoint union of $\sigma C_Q$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right; they only intersect at the endpoints. P.S. In Western culture, calling someone sir is unusual (not rude, just strange).

Comment: Thanks @PeterHumphries , I am from India and we usually say professors as 'Sir', Can you suggest me any reference regarding this because I want to learn this.